# Placing default values using php in input fields is cleared by angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an array

```
$result=array(
    ['firstname'] => 'xyz' ,
    ['lastname'] => 'abc');
```

this array value echoed in value attribute of input fields of html form

```
<form name="myForm"  action = "<?php echo base_url('welcome/submission');?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $result['firstname']; ?>" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/">
    <span ng-show="myForm.firstname.$dirty && myForm.firstname.$error.required" style="color:red;">Your name is required.</span>
     <span ng-show="myForm.firstname.$dirty && myForm.firstname.$error.pattern" style="color:red;">invalid Entry.</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" ng-model="lastname" value="<?php echo $result['lastname']; ?>" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.lastname.$dirty && myForm.lastname.$error.required" style="color:red;" >Last Name is required</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.lastname.$dirty && myForm.lastname.$error.pattern" style="color:red;">invalid Entry.</span>
</form>
```

This is angular js code

```
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
     $scope.submitForm = function() {
     alert("123");
    //$scope.submitted = true;
    if (myForm.$valid) {
        alert('Form submitted - fields passed validation');
    }

  }; 
}); 
</script>
```

I need Values should be placed properly in the value attribute of input field but  it does not happen. All i can see blank input fields if i inspect element value attribute is filled with proper data but not seen in the window.
[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]

Comment: what is the output of <?php echo $result['lastname']; ?>, Have you checked your CSS if that is hiding your ECHO? use firebug or chrome console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, you have to pass the php variable to the first name model in your angular controller.

That’s where angular is reading the value from

```
$scope.firstname = "<?php echo $result['firstname']; ?>";
```

Comment: Thank you it worked after seeing your answer i realized that angular js works on two way binding.